# ASP.NET Core Identity - UserManager and UserStore woes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement the Identity system in an `ASP.NET Core` app (`RC2` libraries) and there is a particular hangup that is driving me crazy.

First of all, I am **not** using EntityFramework. I'm not even using SQL. I'm backing up to **RavenDB**, so I need the implementation to be very specific to that; Which isn't a problem.

So I designed a `RavenUserStore` class, and it looks like this;

```
public class RavenUserStore<TUser> :
        IUserStore<TUser>,
        IUserLoginStore<TUser>,
        IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
        IUserRoleStore<TUser>,
        IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>,
        IUserClaimStore<TUser>,
        IUserLockoutStore<TUser>,
        IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>,
        IUserEmailStore<TUser> {
    // ...
}
```

Works great on its own. I've implemented all the methods, etc. It's wonderful. Very clean and efficient.

Now, I go over to my web application and wire things up;

```
services.AddTransient<ILookupNormalizer>(s => new LowerInvariantLookupNormalizer());
services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<Member>>(s => new PasswordHasher<Member>());
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<Member>, RavenUserStore<Member>>();
services.AddIdentity<Member, Role>(o => {
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddUserStore<RavenUserStore<Member>>()
.AddRoleStore<RavenRoleStore<Role>>();
```

So I go make a controller to use this, per all the samples I've seen, and the very core sample from the [Identity Framework Github Repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs)

```
//... [PROPERTIES]...//
public AccountController(UserManager<Member> userManager, SignInManager<Member> signInManager) {
    // ... [attach constructor parameters to properties] ...//
}
```

Alright, so I inspect the classes carefully.

`UserManager<T>` has a property `Store`,which is a type of `IUserStore<T>`.

So theoretically.. if the dependency injection resolves types of `IUserStore<T>` to `RavenUserStore<T>` when they are injected through a constructor.. shouldn't that mean that the `UserManager<T>` gets a `RavenUserStore<T>` as its Store property?

I thought it would too; But when I call methods on the `UserManager`, it **DOES NOT** call the ones on my `RavenUserStore`. Why is this? What can I do?

Do I really have to ALSO make a custom `UserManager` class and do all of those methods AGAIN?

Comment: try changing AddTransient for your userstore to AddScoped, I think most of the identity objects are scoped per request so yours should be too

Comment: I was hopeful, but no - that didn't work. :(

Comment: you might get some ideas looking through my [cloudscribe project](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe), I have working multi-tenant identity implementation that can use EF but the data layer is abstracted away from the identity bits. of particular interest might be the 3 startup classes in the example.Webapp project where I'm wiring up the services and configuring the middleware. I think all your custom services.Add should go before .AddIdentity and everything should be scoped per request. seems like you are newing up password hasher instead of injecting it.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your example it looks as if making another UserManager class is the only answer.

Comment: That should not be required user store and role store should be sufficient, I needed more methods than the built in usermanager provides is why I implemented it

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to be behaving that way. I'm unsure what else to do.

Comment: Do you know of any samples that don't make a UserManager and still work?

Comment: have you completely removed anything else that could be registering userstore/rolestore with DI? ie remove all references to EF, then yours should be the only one it can get. if it isn't getting yours but it is not null then it is getting some other implementation that must be registered with DI

Comment: Yeah I've removed everything. It's exactly as I posted it up there.

Comment: It wouldn't even compile when I tried 'AddScoped'

Comment: would need to see your project.json and all of your startup code to really diagnose the problem

Comment: Sure. I'm not at the PC right now, but I'll get there soon and put it up for you

Comment: playing with RC2 before it is released you are on the bleeding edge which makes things more difficult, I'm still on rc1

Comment: Yeah, but RC 2 is so different from RC1 that it's almost a complete re-write of the entire program I was working on. I might as well so it as it goes along so I'm there and experienced in the changes than get hit with them all at once

Comment: It doesn't compile, since there are things needed from other parts of the project, but I took the things related to the identity system and made a repository so you can see it in better view. I've got to go somewhere right now, but when I get back I'll try to clean it up more if necessary: https://github.com/ciel/sunfire-stackoverflow

Comment: Would you please post the `AddScoped` reply as an official answer so I may comment on the extension method conundrum and award you credit? Invariably, you were right - I just had an additional problem obfuscating it.

Comment: I am not sure if this would help you, but i had the same problem and after an hour of debugging, and finding that I didn't even assign the identity result to anything, I was unable to inspect the result which ended up saying the "roll head on keyboard"-made password didn't meet password validation rules. All I saw was my CreateAsync just didn't get called despite being able to see my custom UserStore as the Store property of the UserManager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own custom providers *before* calling `services.AddIdentity()`. Internally, `AddIdentity` uses `TryAddScoped()` which only adds the default items if they don't already exist in the services container.

So just putting the call to `AddIdentity()` after you registered all your custom implementations should mean that they will take precedence as you expect.